# Modifying hoverformat in plotly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, plotly

How would I make it so that when hovering over a plotly graph, the displayed value in the hoverbox can be divided by 1000 and have a "K" appended to it?

For instance, when hovering over "$10,000,000" in a plotly graph, what could be done so that "$10,000K" is displayed in the box?

Specifically, can anything be done with the "hoverformat" property? It currently looks like this:

```
hoverformat: ",.0f"
```

I'm aware that this prints a float with 0 decimal places...but how would I specify the displayed value to be divided by 1000 and then have a "K" appended?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using numeral for that purpose. Numeral is a library used to format numbers and you can find it here:

http://numeraljs.com/

You then could do something like

```
const number = 10000;
const formattedNumber = numeral(10000).format('$ 0.00 a');
```